# Share Folder Locally

Tags: networking, sharing

*I expect there is already an answer to this, but I can't find it. Feel free to point me to an existing solution.*

A while ago I did a lot of fiddling about with a terminal on my Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 desktop to set up Nitroshare for copying files to my laptop and possibly Samba, via the wireless links from those computers through my wireless modem. Eventually I installed nautilus-share and managed to share a folder from Nautilus with my laptop which was much more useful. I also had to use a terminal to type:

```
service nmbd start
```

and/or

```
service smbd start
```

and do a restart between. I probably also had to do something to make this stay running for next time I started the desktop.

That setup got lost in an OS change/update, so I need to do it again. Unfortunately when I look at my notes I’m lost in all the detail of what I tried and abandoned.

Ubuntu Budgie uses Nemo, so I have enabled folder sharing with Budgie>Welcome/Recommendations>Nemo Share, right-clicked the folder and shared it, but the laptop doesn't see the share. Fiddling about with

```
service nmbd start
```

and/or

```
service smbd start
```

doesn’t work as I don't really know what I'm doing.

I can’t find a guide that doesn’t talk about servers and give loads of commands that don’t seem necessary. What do I need to do? No sarcy comments about making clearer notes next time please :)

---

Ubuntu Budgie 19.10

Comment: No, I'm using U Budgie. The Samba commands don't work.  http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/what-is-samba-server-and-how-to-setup-samba-server-in-ubuntu-linux in section 2. Configure File Server – Anonymous Share does most of it but not all, I'll post an answer when I've documented it.

Answer (score 0):

Why fiddle with samba if you can use NFS?

NFS has an easy config to select what you want to share, full with permissions and user credentials.

After you create a NFS share, you can mount it on your laptop. You can also automount this share on your laptop, and everything just works. For the automount I use a bash script like

`sleep 1m
mount <nfs server>:/<share name> /mountLocation`

I use this script because my wifi is slow with connections, thus rendering fstab mounting unfeasible.

You can read more [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-an-nfs-share-in-linux/).

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand any of that. It would seem a better plan to stick with what I've got and try and sort that out.

Comment: It is quite easy, I will try to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problems were caused by me following various posts I had seen (before I opened this thread here) which advised things like restarting the Samba and Name servers (sudo systemctl restart smbd.service nmbd.service - *don't do this*).

Changing folder ownership to 'nobody' as Windows allegedly doesn't understand ownership details (sudo chown nobody:nogroup ~/Shared  - *don't do this*) . That caused a problem with Samba because it won't allow you to share other people's folders, so I had to edit the Samba configuration file (/etc/samba/smb.conf) to add a line to the [global] section (usershare owner only = false - *don't do this*). That finally finished it off completely. *Don't do any of this!*

In fact, Ubuntu Budgie starts Samba server by default so I didn't have to do anything to that and there is no problem with the other computer on Windows (7) handling a directory owned by me. If I had ignored everyone and done nothing, it would all have just worked!